# How to solve TLS handshake failed error?

Tags: apt, software-installation, proxy, sublime-text, tls

I was trying to install sublime text on my ubuntu 18.04. The method I tried to install Sublime Text is to follow this link [Linux Package Manager Repositories](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/linux_repositories.html#apt) but it throws below error when I issue the `apt update`

```
Err:8 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ Release                     
  Could not handshake: An unexpected TLS packet was received. [IP: 136.17.0.7 83]
```

I don't think this related with proxy setup correct me if I'm wrong. I just checked with upgrade my git to latest. I added ppa and issued apt update and it installed latest version. So now my question is why this not work with Sublime Text?

Note: I'm using this machine behind corporate proxy and I will provide more information if you need anything. I searched online and end up nothing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [apt update: Could not handshake: An unexpected TLS packet was received](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1014973/apt-update-could-not-handshake-an-unexpected-tls-packet-was-received) and [Unable to run Sublime Text 3 on Ubuntu 18.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1090947/)

Comment: @karel My apt.conf.d/01proxy configuration is right. In fact I tried to update the git using the ppa method and that was working fine. Now my question is why not this work with sublime?

Comment: Sublime text editor is a native Ubuntu snap package in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. You can install Sublime text editor 3 from Ubuntu Software now instead of using the ppa method, and then Sublime text editor will receive updates automatically.

Comment: Is that mean I can install it from Ubuntu Software Centre? I searched and it returned nothing.

Comment: Open the terminal and type: `sudo snap install sublime-text --classic`