# W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'Sources' as repository does not seem to provide it (sources.list entry misspelt?)

Tags: apt, updates, software-sources, sublime-text

Ran: `sudo apt-get update`

Output:

```
.
.
.
Reading package lists... Done
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'Sources' as repository 'https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease' does not seem to provide it (sources.list entry misspelt?)
```

sources.list

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/
deb-src https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg main
```

How to resolve it?

Edit:
I have referred [Unable to run Sublime Text 3 on Ubuntu 18.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1090947/unable-to-run-sublime-text-3-on-ubuntu-18-10) But this didn't helped.

Comment: Post your `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: Did you follow this Guidelines: https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/linux_repositories.html#apt

Comment: No, I have downloaded from store. Let me try it again.

Comment: This is my sources.list regarding sublime.

Comment: My sources.list regarding sublime is updated in question. @Johnny

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Programmatically using `sed`, you can run this command to comment the `deb-src` line of `download.sublimetext.com` :

```
sudo sed -e '\@deb-src https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/@ s@^#*@#@' -i /etc/apt/sources.list
```

The results will be the same.

---

Open up `/etc/apt/sources.list` through `nano` as root.

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>, type `deb-src https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/` on the search bar, then you can put `#` in beginning of the line to comment it— you can also delete the line altogether.

Run `sudo apt update` again, see if you'll get the same errors.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Now, I am facing "W: Target Packages (Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list:1
"

Comment: @WhatIf That's for another [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Thanks. I will make it.

Comment: Posted. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1192182/w-target-packages-packages-is-configured-multiple-times-in-etc-apt-sources-l

Comment: It's done. Thank you.