# W: Target Packages (Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list:1

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, sublime-text

Ran: `sudo apt-get update`

Output:

```
.
.
.
Reading package lists... Done
W: Target Packages (Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list:1
```

sources.list

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/
# deb-src https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg main
```

How to resolve it?

Edit:
I have referred [How can I fix apt error "W: Target Packages ... is configured multiple times"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760896/how-can-i-fix-apt-error-w-target-packages-is-configured-multiple-times) But this didn't helped.

Comment: Still I am getting error.

Comment: short and painless `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list`

Comment: @nobody Great!!! It solved my problem. Now, I am getting a different problem 
 GPG error: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic

Comment: @nobody Post it as answer.

Comment: GPG error is solved with the help of https://askubuntu.com/questions/20725/gpg-error-the-following-signatures-couldnt-be-verified-because-the-public-key